# Include tikz image in other text files of each chapter

Tags: macros, sectioning, chapters, tikz-external

I am working on a book which each chapter has an image .jpg or .png. The code that accomplishes this is:

```
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}}
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering \normalfont\sffamily
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};

%Comentando las 3 líneas de abajo quita la caja de contenidos en el título del capítulo
\draw[rounded corners=10pt, fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1cm,0cm) rectangle (8cm,-9.3cm);                   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% minitabla
\node[anchor=north west] at (1cm,.25cm) {\parbox[t][8cm][t]{6.5cm}{\huge\bfseries\flushleft \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}};

\draw[anchor=west] (5cm,-9cm) node [rounded corners=25pt,fill=white,fill opacity=.6,text opacity=1,draw=colordominante,draw opacity=1,line width=2pt,inner sep=15pt]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{black}{\thechapter\ ---\ #1\vphantom{plPQq}\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\par\vspace*{230\p@}
```

In the main document, you would call the name of a figure just before the chapter command:

```
\chapterimage{imagen4.png} 
\chapter{Estadística y probabilidad}
```

Whose generated image is

[image]

The question is whether it is possible to modify the previous code where a .tex file that directly draws the image is inserted, something like `\chapterimage{\input{pascal.tex}}` this because if only one image is included it loses quality.

**Edited 2:** `Main file`

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,x11names,table,openany,usenames,dvipsnames]{book}                                                  
% Dimensiones y márgenes.                                                 
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{Preambulo}% = Paquetes y código de diseño
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Tabla de contenidos
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{imagen4.png} % Foto en tabla de contenidos
\pagestyle{empty}          % Pág sin encabezado
\tableofcontents 

\cleardoublepage  %
\pagestyle{fancy} % Encabezados

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Capítulo 1
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{imagen4.png} 
\chapter{Estadística y probabilidad}

\section{Estadística}

Para datos no agrupados.

\subsection{Conceptos básicos}

Text text text 

\end{document}
```

File called `Preambulo`

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paquetes y estilo del libro 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paquetes 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                      % Entrada de acentos
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle, spanish = mexican]{csquotes}% manejo de comillas: ``__ "
\linespread{1.05}                                  % Fuente Palatino necesita espaciado
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}                        % Caracteres especiales como ' (recto)
\usepackage{xcolor}                                % Color: X11names (en el documentclass)
\usepackage{ifsym}          %número digitales
% COLORES personales---http://latexcolor.com/---------------------------------
    \definecolor{colortitulo}{RGB}{219,68,14} % 
    \definecolor{colordominante}{RGB}{243,102,25}
    \definecolor{colordominanteF}{RGB}{219,68,14}
    \definecolor{colordominanteD}{RGB}{137,46,55}
    \definecolor{mostaza}{RGB}{231,196,25}
    \definecolor{amarilloM}{RGB}{248,199,90}
    \definecolor{amarilloD}{RGB}{251,237,121}
    \definecolor{grisamarillo}{RGB}{248,248,245} 
    \definecolor{azulF}{rgb}{.0,.0,.3}
    \definecolor{grisD}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}
    \definecolor{grisF}{rgb}{.6,.6,.6}

% Fin COLORES personales-------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}                             % Cajas de Teoremas, ejemplos, etc.
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}                    % Librerías tcolorbox
\usepackage{xargs}                                 % Comandos con opciones
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,backgrounds,calc}%
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,cancel,stmaryrd,amsthm}%
\usepackage[ruled,,vlined,lined,linesnumbered,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}% Conversión - Miktes 2.9 o inferior, TexLive 2009. o inferior
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=azulF,
citecolor=azulF, urlcolor=azulF]{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

%Animaciones
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,backgrounds}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fuentes
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Comandos para fuentes especiales
\newcommandx*{\fnte}[4][1=pag,2=9,3=n]{{\color{azulF}\fontfamily{#1}\fontsize{#2}{1}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont{#4}}}

\newcommandx*{\fntb}[4][1=pag,2=9,3=n]{{\color{azulF}\fontfamily{#1}\fontsize{#2}{1}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont{#4}}}

\newcommandx*{\fntg}[4][1=pag,2=9,3=n]{{\color{grisF}\fontfamily{#1}\fontsize{#2}{1}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont{#4}}}

\newcommand{\fhv}[2]{{\fontfamily{pag}\fontsize{#1}{1}\selectfont{#2}}}

\newcommand{\fhvb}[2]{{\fontfamily{pag}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{#1}{1}\selectfont{#2}}}
% Fin fuentes----------------------------------------------------------



%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%tabla de contenidofotos
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % Permite la personalización de títulos
\usepackage{graphicx} % Requerido para la inclusión de imágenes
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reducir el espacio entre las viñetas y listas numeradas
\usepackage{booktabs} % Necesario para reglas horizontales más bonitas en las tablas
\usepackage{eso-pic} % Requerido para especificar una imagen de fondo en la página del título

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Tabla de contenidos
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Necesario para manipular la tabla de contenido

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Elimina el margen predeterminado
% Estilo del texto en "Capítulo"
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentación
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Espaciado y fuente, opciones de capítulos
{\color{colordominante!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{colordominante}} % Chapter number
{}  
{\color{colordominante!60}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
% Estilo del texto Sección
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentación
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Espaciado y fuente, opciones de las secciones
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\sffamily\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% Estilo del texto Subsección
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentación
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Espaciado y fuente opciones para las subsecciones
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\sffamily\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[] 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLA DE CONTENIDO DE CADA CAPÍTULO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indentando
{\footnotesize\sffamily}      % Fuentes
{}
{}
{}

% Estilo del texto Subsección
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em]   % Indentando
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Fuentes
{}
{}
{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Encabezados de página
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Necesario para la cabecera y el pie de página de configuración
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Fuente capítulo
% Texto en secciones
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} 
% Configuración de fuentes para el número de página en el encabezado
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} %
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Ancho de la norma bajo el encabezado
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Aumente el espacio alrededor de la cabecera 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Elimina la línea en el pie de página
% Estilo para cuando se especifica "pagestyle plain"
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} 

% Elimina el encabezado de las páginas impares vacías al final de los capítulos
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Numeración de las secciones -- en el margen
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{colordominante}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}                    
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{0.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}                        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{0.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Diseño inicio de capítulos
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}}
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering \normalfont\sffamily
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};

%Comentando las 3 líneas de abajo quita la caja de contenidos en el título del capítulo
\draw[rounded corners=10pt, fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1cm,0cm) rectangle (8cm,-7.0cm);                   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% minitabla
\node[anchor=north west] at (1cm,.25cm) {\parbox[t][8cm][t]{6.5cm}{\huge\bfseries\flushleft \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}};

\draw[anchor=west] (5cm,-9cm) node [rounded corners=25pt,fill=white,fill opacity=.6,text opacity=1,draw=colordominante,draw opacity=1,line width=2pt,inner sep=15pt]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{black}{\thechapter\ ---\ #1\vphantom{plPQq}\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\par\vspace*{230\p@}
\fi
\fi
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering \normalfont\sffamily
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west] at (-4pt,4pt) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};
\draw[anchor=west] (5cm,-9.cm) node [rounded corners=25pt,fill=white,opacity=.6,inner sep=18pt]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{black}{\vphantom{plPQq}\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\draw[anchor=west] (5cm,-9cm) node [rounded corners=25pt,draw=colordominante,line width=2pt,inner sep=15pt]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{black}{#1\vphantom{plPQq}\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\par\vspace*{230\p@}
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Image

[image]

File called `pascal` that I want to include in place of the image, something like `(\chapterimage{\input{pascal}})`

```
\documentclass{standalone}%

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialCoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newdimen\R
\R=.4cm
\newcommand\mycolor{gray}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8pt]
\fill[cyan!50] (-460pt,-270pt) rectangle (140pt,30pt);

  \foreach \k in {0,...,12}{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-60:{sqrt(3)*\R*\k})}]
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ystart{12-\k}
      \foreach \n in {0,...,\ystart}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\newn{\n+\k}
        \ifthenelse{\k=0}{\def\mycolor{pink}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\k=1}{\def\mycolor{yellow}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\k=2}{\def\mycolor{blue}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\k=3}{\def\mycolor{green}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\k=8 \AND \n < 4}{\def\mycolor{purple}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\k=9 \AND \n = 3}{\def\mycolor{purple}}{}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(-120:{sqrt(3)*\R*\n})}]
           \draw[top color=\mycolor!20,bottom color=\mycolor!60] 
             (30:\R) \foreach \x in {90,150,...,330} {
                -- (\x:\R)}
                -- cycle (90:0)
                   node {\tiny $\mathbf{\binomialCoefficient{\newn}{\k}}$};
         \end{scope}
      }
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a full compilable code. Note that you are nesting `tikzpicture`s (by putting a `tikzpicture` into the node of another `tikzpicture`), which should be avoided. Also I am wondering why this is tagged `tikz-external` (rather than just `tikz-pgf`).

Comment: Sorry, many users here, including myself, do not follow external links. Please just edit your code such that it starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and illustrates what you want. And if you want make your question read by Ti*k*Z users, avoid nesting `tikzpicture`s as this has consequences that are hard to control.

Comment: @marmot excuse the delay, I simplified the files as far as I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this qualifies as an answer. However, if you do not convert your self-created image to png put just keep it in the pdf format, there won't be any quality loss.

The reason why I am posting an answer here is to tell you that you should really not nest `tikzpicture`s. And there is no need for it either. You could just use [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799) to put whatever on top of your included graphics. Specifically, there is a local coordinate system coming with that answer which makes the placement a bit more intuitive. (Note that here because of the absolute positioning and the fact that the `north west` anchor is used, `y` becomes larger when moving down.) Your `Preambulo.tex` file then becomes

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paquetes y estilo del libro 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paquetes 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                      % Entrada de acentos
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle, spanish = mexican]{csquotes}% manejo de comillas: ``__ "
\linespread{1.05}                                  % Fuente Palatino necesita espaciado
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}                        % Caracteres especiales como ' (recto)
\usepackage{xcolor}                                % Color: X11names (en el documentclass)
\usepackage{ifsym}          %número digitales
% COLORES personales---http://latexcolor.com/---------------------------------
    \definecolor{colortitulo}{RGB}{219,68,14} % 
    \definecolor{colordominante}{RGB}{243,102,25}
    \definecolor{colordominanteF}{RGB}{219,68,14}
    \definecolor{colordominanteD}{RGB}{137,46,55}
    \definecolor{mostaza}{RGB}{231,196,25}
    \definecolor{amarilloM}{RGB}{248,199,90}
    \definecolor{amarilloD}{RGB}{251,237,121}
    \definecolor{grisamarillo}{RGB}{248,248,245} 
    \definecolor{azulF}{rgb}{.0,.0,.3}
    \definecolor{grisD}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}
    \definecolor{grisF}{rgb}{.6,.6,.6}

% Fin COLORES personales-------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}                             % Cajas de Teoremas, ejemplos, etc.
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}                    % Librerías tcolorbox
\usepackage{xargs}                                 % Comandos con opciones
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,backgrounds,calc}%
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,cancel,stmaryrd,amsthm}%
\usepackage[ruled,,vlined,lined,linesnumbered,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}% Conversión - Miktes 2.9 o inferior, TexLive 2009. o inferior
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=azulF,
citecolor=azulF, urlcolor=azulF]{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

%Animaciones
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,backgrounds}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fuentes
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Comandos para fuentes especiales
\newcommandx*{\fnte}[4][1=pag,2=9,3=n]{{\color{azulF}\fontfamily{#1}\fontsize{#2}{1}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont{#4}}}

\newcommandx*{\fntb}[4][1=pag,2=9,3=n]{{\color{azulF}\fontfamily{#1}\fontsize{#2}{1}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont{#4}}}

\newcommandx*{\fntg}[4][1=pag,2=9,3=n]{{\color{grisF}\fontfamily{#1}\fontsize{#2}{1}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont{#4}}}

\newcommand{\fhv}[2]{{\fontfamily{pag}\fontsize{#1}{1}\selectfont{#2}}}

\newcommand{\fhvb}[2]{{\fontfamily{pag}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{#1}{1}\selectfont{#2}}}
% Fin fuentes----------------------------------------------------------



%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%tabla de contenidofotos
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % Permite la personalización de títulos
\usepackage{graphicx} % Requerido para la inclusión de imágenes
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reducir el espacio entre las viñetas y listas numeradas
\usepackage{booktabs} % Necesario para reglas horizontales más bonitas en las tablas
\usepackage{eso-pic} % Requerido para especificar una imagen de fondo en la página del título

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Tabla de contenidos
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Necesario para manipular la tabla de contenido

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Elimina el margen predeterminado
% Estilo del texto en "Capítulo"
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentación
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Espaciado y fuente, opciones de capítulos
{\color{colordominante!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{colordominante}} % Chapter number
{}  
{\color{colordominante!60}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
% Estilo del texto Sección
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentación
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Espaciado y fuente, opciones de las secciones
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\sffamily\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% Estilo del texto Subsección
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentación
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Espaciado y fuente opciones para las subsecciones
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\sffamily\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[] 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLA DE CONTENIDO DE CADA CAPÍTULO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indentando
{\footnotesize\sffamily}      % Fuentes
{}
{}
{}

% Estilo del texto Subsección
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em]   % Indentando
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Fuentes
{}
{}
{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Encabezados de página
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Necesario para la cabecera y el pie de página de configuración
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Fuente capítulo
% Texto en secciones
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} 
% Configuración de fuentes para el número de página en el encabezado
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} %
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Ancho de la norma bajo el encabezado
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Aumente el espacio alrededor de la cabecera 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Elimina la línea en el pie de página
% Estilo para cuando se especifica "pagestyle plain"
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} 

% Elimina el encabezado de las páginas impares vacías al final de los capítulos
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Numeración de las secciones -- en el margen
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{colordominante}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}                    
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{0.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}                        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{0.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Diseño inicio de capítulos
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}}
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering \normalfont\sffamily
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] (image) at (current page.north west)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};
\begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=-4pt,yshift=4pt]current page.north
west)},x={(image.north east)},y={(image.south west)}]
%Comentando las 3 líneas de abajo quita la caja de contenidos en el título del capítulo
 \node[anchor=north west,rounded corners=10pt, fill=white,opacity=0.5] at 
 (0.05,0.1) {\parbox[t][8cm][t]{6.5cm}{\huge\bfseries\flushleft \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}};
 \draw[anchor=west] (0.2,0.8) node [rounded corners=25pt,fill=white,fill opacity=.6,text opacity=1,draw=colordominante,draw opacity=1,line width=2pt,inner sep=15pt]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{black}{\thechapter\ ---\ #1\vphantom{plPQq}\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\par\vspace*{230\p@}
\fi
\fi
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering \normalfont\sffamily
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799
\node[anchor=north west] (image) at ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=4pt]current page.north west)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};
\begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=-4pt,yshift=4pt]current page.north
west)},x={(image.north east)},y={(image.south west)}]
 \draw[anchor=west] (0.2,0.4) node [rounded corners=25pt,fill=white,opacity=.6,inner sep=18pt]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{black}{\vphantom{plPQq}\makebox[22cm]{}}};
 \draw[anchor=west] (0.2,0.4) node [rounded corners=25pt,draw=colordominante,line width=2pt,inner sep=15pt]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{black}{#1\vphantom{plPQq}\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\par\vspace*{230\p@}
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Whether or not these are the precise locations of the title and the table of contents, I don't know, but with [Jake's local coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799) that is being used here it should be straightforward to move things to the desired position.

Comment: did not know that PDFs maintain the quality of the images, I'm left with this solution is simple and efficient, thank you very much.

Comment: @SamuelDiaz You're welcome!